# How I can organize data filtering on several checkboxes and the search field using pipes?

Tags: angular

I continue to study Angular 6 and I ran into the fact that I can not figure out how I can organize data filtering on several checkboxes and the search field using pipes. I read many forums and lessons, but I can not understand this task.

Here are the clippings from the code:

My component:

```ts
import { Component, OnInit, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { AdminService } from '../admin.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-app-module',
  templateUrl: './app-module.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app-module.component.scss']
})

export class AppModuleComponent implements OnInit {
   public data: {
    services: [
      {
        id: number,
        name: string,
        url: string,
        connected: boolean,
        used: boolean,
        warning: boolean
      }

    ]
  };
  public services: any = [];
  constructor(private adminService: AdminService) { }


  ngOnInit() {
    this.getServicesList();
  }

  getServicesList() {
    this.adminService.getServices()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        this.services = data.services;
      });
  }
}
```

My service:

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class AdminService {
private API = 'http://localhost:3000';
constructor(
    private _http: HttpClient
) { }
getServices(): Observable<any> {
return this._http.get<any>(this.API + '/services');
}
}
```

My component.html

```html
<div class="bg-gray wraper d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
  <div class="ui-card d-flex flex-column">
    <div>
      <strong>App Integration</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="search-box py-3">

      <form class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
        <input class="form-control form-search mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
        <input class="ui-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="connected">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="connected">
          Connected
        </label>
        <input class="ui-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="discovered">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="discovered">
          Discovered (not connected)
        </label>
        <input class="ui-checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" id="unused">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="unused">
          Unused
        </label>
      </form>


    </div>
    <div class="ui-services-box d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between">
      <div *ngFor="let service of services"
      class="ui-service d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between align-items-center"
      [ngClass]="{'brd-warning': service.warning}"
      [style.border-color]="!service.connected || !service.used ? '#9ea5b5':'#2bc339'"

      >
        <img src="{{service.url}}" alt="">
        <p>{{service.name}}</p>
        <div *ngIf="service.warning" ><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div *ngIf="!service.used" ><i class="fa fa-lock" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
        <div
        class="button-green"
        *ngIf="service.used"
        [style.background-color]="service.connected === 0 ? '#9ea5b5': '#2bc339'">
          {{ service.connected ? "Connected" : "Connect" }}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My data:

```ts
services = [
{
id: 1,
    url: './assets/img/services/atlassian.png',
    name: 'Atlassian',
    connected: 1,
    used: 1,
    warning: 0 
},
{
    id: 2,
    url: './assets/img/services/google.png',
    name: 'Google G Suite',
    connected: 1,
    used: 1,
    warning: 1
 },
{
    id: 3,
    url: './assets/img/services/salesforce.svg',
    name: 'Salesforce',
    connected: 0,
    used: 1,
    warning: 1
 }
]
```

Below is a screenshot, it shows that all the services are displayed on the page, there is a search field in the top and three checkboxes, I want the list of services to be sorted by the name that I drive in the search field and the values ​​of the checkboxes.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry but too much code is overwhelming to me, especially when not syntax colored. Could you please state what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: @trichetriche, above, I added a screen and what I want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following your screenshot, you should create a pipe. You would use it like this :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="query">
<div *ngFor="let provider of providers | fullSearch:query:'name'">
```

And in your pipe

```
transform(items: any[], query: string, property: string) {
  return items.filter(item => item[property].includes(query));
}
```

I'm sorry I can't provide code adapted to your case or documentation, but right now I'm on phone and it's not convenient at all. Either notify me with a comment tomorrow, or find the documentation on your own !

Comment: Hi, I did the filter as you showed me, and it works great. But still I did not achieve the desired result. I need that, in addition to the filter on the search field, the data is also filtered and checkboxes.
That is, I have a service that for example is not connected and there is a service that is connected. Clicking on checkbox connected I want to see only connected services, and clicking on the Discovered check box in addition, I want to get services that are both connected and not connected.
Help please. @trichetriche

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean, you need to filter based on what you enter in the search? Sorry I cannot post comments yet.